# Swift How to update url of video in AVPlayer when clicking on a button?

Tags: ios, swift, video-player

I have a video player in an IOS App and I want to update the video when I click on a button, but I do not see how to manage this.
(Note : it's not a list of video within a queue)

Here is the code for adding the AVPlayer:

```
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player
..

..
self.ViewForVideo.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
self.addChildViewController(playerViewController)

player.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done like this : each time I want to change the video I create a new `AVPlayer` and affect it to the `playerViewController.player` like this

```
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
playerViewController.player = player
```